# Change WooCommerce Email Header using custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to change the woocommerce email header template with a new one so that I could add conditions in header template to get value from the dashboard (To change the color of header based on user input from the dashboard). I have created a plugin file to do so.

I have followed several tutorials and all I received is a bunch of errors.
I have a class with the following code:

```
public function __construct(){
    add_action('woocommerce_email',array($this,'woocommerce_email'));
}
```

Now I have added code to remove default header hook

```
public function woocommerce_email($mailer){

    remove_action('woocommerce_header',array($mailer,'email_header'));
    add_action('woocommerce_header',array($this,'email_header'));
```

now calling the template

```
public function email_header() {          
    wc_get_template( 'emails/email-header.php');
}
```

I am not passing anything to the template file. So no parameters are passed to functions. I just wanted to see that my template is being taken.
Also, I assume `$mailer` to be a part of the woocommerce class. Any help would be appreciated.

Please note that this is a plugin functionality so I am not interested in replacing the woocommerce email templates.

Comment: you don't need to unhook / rehook. just create a file in your theme directory in `woocommerce/emails/email-header.php` and the original e-mail submission will use it

Comment: But i am trying to create a plugin. Not a theme development. This plugin is used for all themes.  So instead of taking email templates from woocommerce plugin, it has to take custom templates created in my plugin directory

Comment: Then in the method `email_header` of your class, just display the file of your plugin, with `require` e.g.

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove action woocommmerce_email_header

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'email_header');
```

Which was registered at

```
wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-emails.php
```

Than add your own action

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_header','your_function_name');
```

your function should output html

default there is below code in header template

```
<?php
/**
 * Email Header
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-header.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 2.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ); ?></title>
    </head>
    <body <?php echo is_rtl() ? 'rightmargin' : 'leftmargin'; ?>="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
        <div id="wrapper" dir="<?php echo is_rtl() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'?>">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <div id="template_header_image">
                            <?php
                                if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
                                    echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) . '" /></p>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_container">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- Header -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_header">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="header_wrapper">
                                                <h1><?php echo $email_heading; ?></h1>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- End Header -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- Body -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_body">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" id="body_content">
                                                <!-- Content -->
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top">
                                                            <div id="body_content_inner">
```

Comment: But that doesnt show me the new content.

Comment: your function should output code

Comment: It still takes the woocommerce default header

Comment: where does you write code ? In theme ?

Comment: plugin file. I have created a plugin file

Comment: it should work than

Comment: The code looks great. Let me check my code again.

Comment: If my email header template file contain nothing but just an echo , does woocommerce take default one ? @malaysolanki

Comment: yes it should work

Comment: Thanks bro. Its working. It was a mistake in my action hook name. Regards @Malaysolanki

Comment: Do you know why image is not shown in email header ? img tag is shown on inspecting browser

Comment: Give fix height and width inline

Comment: Let me try and i will let u know. You are the best helper. Thanks for your helping mentality @Malay

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. Since i have low reputation, i cannot mark this answer . I will do it when i have sufficient reputation to do so @malaysolanki

Answer (score 2):

For someone doing this from your theme.

1. Copy the contents of the email template that you can find here:

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-header.php

2. Paste the contents of the file in 1. in the following path

yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-header.php

3. Optional if you need the order object to get a data your need to add the following in your functions.php

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'email_header_before', 1, 2 );
    function email_header_before( $email_heading, $email ){
        $GLOBALS['email'] = $email;
    }
```

4. Optional, and then in the template file you just create it use it this way

```
// Call the global WC_Email object
global $email;

// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = $email->object;
```

Step 3 and 4, obtained from this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739353/get-the-order-object-in-woocommerce-email-header-template

by @LoicTheAztec